# Limiting both the fractional and total number of digits when formatting a float for display

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnumberformatter, decimal-point

I need to print a float value in area of limited width most efficiently. I'm using an `NSNumberFormatter`, and I set two numbers after the decimal point as the default, so that when I have a number like `234.25` it is printed as is: `234.25`. But when I have `1234.25` I want it to be printed as: `1234.3`, and  `11234.25` should be printed `11234`.

I need a maximum of two digits after the point, and a maximum of five digits overall if I have digits after the point, but it also should print more than five digits if the integer part has more.

I don't see ability to limit the total number of digits in `NSNumberFormatter`. Does this mean that I should write my own function to format numbers in this way? If so, then what is the correct way of getting the count of digits in the integer and fractional parts of a number? I would also prefer working with `CGFLoat`, rather than `NSNumber` to avoid extra type conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I implemented this in my code. I don't know how efficient it is, I hope not bad.

So I create a global NSNumberFormatter

```
NSNumberFormatter* numFormatter;
```

and initialize it somewhere:

```
numFormatter=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
```

Then I format number with the following function:

```
- (NSString*)formatFloat:(Float32)number withOptimalDigits:(UInt8)optimalDigits maxDecimals:(UInt8)maxDecimals
{
    NSString* result;
    UInt8 intDigits=(int)log10f(number)+1;
    NSLog(@"Formatting %.5f with maxDig: %d maxDec: %d intLength: %d",number,optimalDigits,maxDecimals,intDigits);  

    numFormatter.maximumFractionDigits=maxDecimals;
    if(intDigits>=optimalDigitis-maxDecimals) {
        numFormatter.usesSignificantDigits=YES;
        numFormatter.maximumSignificantDigits=(intDigits>optimalDigits)?intDigits:optimalDigits;
    } else {
        numFormatter.usesSignificantDigits=NO;
    }
    result = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:number]];

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You're looking for a combination of "maximum significant digits" and "maximum fraction digits", along with particular rounding behavior. `NSNumberFormatter` is equal to the task:

```
float twofortythreetwentyfive = 234.25;
float onetwothreefourtwentyfive = 1234.25;
float eleventwothreefourtwentyfive = 11234.25;

NSNumberFormatter * formatter =  [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[formatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:5];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundCeiling];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:twofortythreetwentyfive]]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:onetwothreefourtwentyfive]]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:eleventwothreefourtwentyfive]]);
```

Result:

> 2012-04-26 16:32:04.481 SignificantDigits[11565:707] 234.25
>   2012-04-26 16:32:04.482 SignificantDigits[11565:707] 1234.3
>   2012-04-26 16:32:04.483 SignificantDigits[11565:707] 11235

Comment: Thanks. This looks really simple. But if I have number: 211234.25 it will return 211230. But I would like it to return 211234 so that it only rounds the floating part, and integer part should stay untouched. Is it still possible with NSNumberFormatter?

Comment: So I want that optimally length of my printed number was not larger than 5 digits. So I print it full if it has <=3 integer digits. If has 4 integers and more, I cut decimal part. No changes to integer digits. Only last digit can be changed according to the decimal part.

Comment: But then you don't have a fixed width. I'm honestly not sure how to make `NSNumberFormatter` do that; off the top of my head, you could truncate the input if its log10 (which is approximately equal to length - 1 of integer part) is greater than 5.

Comment: Sorry, I should state it more clearly. By width I meant width in pixels. So I want to use given area in pixels most efficiently to display a number.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think if you want to use `NSNumberFormatter`, you'll have to change the settings a bit each time, if the input number is too long. Otherwise I guess a custom function along the lines of Dr. Kameleon's seems to be the way.

Answer (score 1):

**Code :**

```
#define INTPARTSTR(X) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)X]
#define DECPARTSTR(X) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(((float)X-(int)X)*100)]

- (NSString*)formatFloat:(float)f
{
    NSString* result;

    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",f];

    if ([DECPARTSTR(f) isEqualToString:@"0"]) return INTPARTSTR(f);
    if ([INTPARTSTR(f) length]==5) return INTPARTSTR(f);

    if ([result length]>5)
    {
        int diff = (int)[result length]-7;

        NSString* newResult = @"";

        for (int i=0; i<[result length]-diff-1; i++)
            newResult = [newResult stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c",[result characterAtIndex:i]];

        return newResult;
    }


    return result;
}
```

---

**Testing it :**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[self formatFloat:234.63]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[self formatFloat:1234.65]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[self formatFloat:11234.65]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[self formatFloat:11234]);
}
```

**Output :**

```
2012-04-26 19:27:24.429 newProj[1798:903] 234.63
2012-04-26 19:27:24.432 newProj[1798:903] 1234.6
2012-04-26 19:27:24.432 newProj[1798:903] 11234
2012-04-26 19:27:24.432 newProj[1798:903] 11234
```

Comment: Thanks. This implementation looks quite universal, but I am concerned about the efficiency. Can something more efficient than NSString be used? Or there is no way to count number of digits in the number besides counting length of string? I'm going to do this conversion continuously in every frame of animation during all time of program running. Will not it be hard?

Comment: @BartoNaz: The base-10 logarithm of a number is approximately the length - 1 of its integer digits: `log10f(11123.25) -> 4.046221`

Comment: Yes, the Logarithms is a good idea. I'll try to make something like @Dr.Kameleon proposed but using logarithm instead of NSString. I think that should work faster.

Comment: @BartoNaz Just read the other comments. And I think I agree too, logs seem like a very interesting addition... :-)

Answer (score -1):

Is this a bug when using `maximumFractionDigits` and `maximumSignificantDigits` together on `NSNumberForamtter` on iOS 8?

```
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;  
        formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 3;
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(0.3333)]); // output 0.333 expected 0.33
```

It works fine if I only use `maximumFractionDigits`

```
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(0.3333)]); // output expected .33
```

[NSNumberFormatter maximumFractionDigits and maximumSignificantDigits bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644341/nsnumberforamtter-maximumfractiondigits-and-maximumsignificantdigits-bug)