# NSNumberFormatter maximumFractionDigits and maximumSignificantDigits bug

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

Is this a bug when using `maximumFractionDigits` and `maximumSignificantDigits` together on `NSNumberForamtter` on iOS 8?

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;  
formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 3;
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(0.3333)]); // output 0.333 expected 0.33
```

It works fine if I only use `maximumFractionDigits`

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(0.3333)]); // output expected .33
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a bug. From the docs:

> **Note**
>
> When a number formatter is configured to use significant digits, it ignores any minimum or maximum values used to set integer or fraction digits.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1417793-usessignificantdigits?language=objc

Note: If either `maximumSignificantDigits` or `minimumSignificantDigits` is set to any value, then `usesSignificantDigits` is automatically set to true. This contradicts the docs for `maximumSignificantDigits` and `minimumSignificantDigits` which says:

> You must set the usesSignificantDigits property to true in order for this property to affect formatting behavior.

You don't need to set `usesSignificantDigits` to true, it will set itself to true.