# Use `Intl.NumberFormat` with `maximumFractionDigits` and `maximumSignificantDigits` at once

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

When running

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  maximumSignificantDigits: 3,
  minimumSignificantDigits: 1 
}).format(10.123456789));
```

I would expect the output to be `10`. Instead for some reason it outputs `10.1` which breaks the `maximumFractionDigits: 0` constraint. What's going on? Considering this constraint is ignored across browsers it seems this is according to specification, but I just can't phantom a reason for this.

Comment: This same behavior seems to be occurring in swift as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644341/nsnumberformatter-maximumfractiondigits-and-maximumsignificantdigits-bug

Comment: It seems like significant digits take priority over fraction digits. I suppose if you really want no fraction digits, you could always `Math.round`, though I agree that's less than ideal.

Answer (score 12):

From the [Intl.NumberFormat parameter descriptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Parameters) (emphasis added):

> The following properties fall into two groups: `minimumIntegerDigits`,
> `minimumFractionDigits`, and `maximumFractionDigits` in one group,
> `minimumSignificantDigits` and `maximumSignificantDigits` in the other. **If
> at least one property from the second group is defined, then the first
> group is ignored.**

There has to be some override behavior to handle property setting conflicts but in your example, one might reasonably wish that the override behavior was not quite so all or nothing (since making the adjustment for the fraction digits limitation falls within the specified range of significant digits). Unfortunately, the spec is simply to ignore any of the fraction or integer digit limitations if the significant digit properties are set.

If anyone comes looking for a way to utilize both types of properties to format a single number, below is a very basic example using the two constructors in succession (beware, this can get messy very quickly with more complex formatting requirements).

```js
const sigDigits = (n, min, max, minf, maxf) => {
  let num = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    minimumSignificantDigits: min,
    maximumSignificantDigits: max
  })
  .format(n);
  
  num = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits: minf,
    maximumFractionDigits: maxf
  })
  .format(num);
  
  return num;
};

const result = sigDigits(10.123456789, 1, 3, 0, 0);
console.log(result);
// 10
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did indeed in the end as well, just was so incredibly confused by this behavior that I just had to ask whether someone knew some rationale or anything... At least it could throw an error in such a case (just like when you provide an out of bound value), but oh well~ weird how they seem to have copied the Swift spec without any critical thought.

Comment: Anyway, my bad for missing that line on the MDN page (I thought it belonged to the grouping parameter). Will probably accept this answer, but will give it a bit whether someone knows of some logical reason.

Comment: @DavidMulder - I am also interested in any insight on the rationale for the blunt instrument override behavior. I suspect it has something to do with difficulty in combining the ToRawPrecision (for significant digits) and ToRawFixed (for fraction digits) operations in the spec but not sure.